# Wi-Fi Direct on Galaxy Mini

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, samsung-galaxy-mini, wifi-direct

I have already Googled a bit, but I haven't found a list specifying the supported devices.

Is it possible to use Wi-Fi Direct on Samsung Galaxy Mini (GT-S5570B with Android 2.3.6 Gingerbread)? Is there a hardware limitation?

Comment: Questions about how to develop/write apps are expressly off topic on this site (see our [FAQ] for more). However, a question simply asking whether or not the Mini supports this seems fine, and I have rephrased your question as such.

Answer (score 1):

*WiFi Direct* can be used on all Android devices. Android 4.0 and higher comes with this feature pre-installed.

If your device runs an older version of Android, you can find many apps in the *Google Playstore* to enable direct file sharing service over WiFi. Go for [SuperBeam](http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.majedev.superbeam), [Fast File Transfer](http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.floriandraschbacher.fastfiletransfer), [WiFi File Transfer](http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.smarterdroid.wififiletransfer), etc.

Comment: Hotspot is not *WiFi Direct*. While the latter clearly is a 1:1 connection, Hotspot is 1:n, as multiple WiFi-enabled devices can connect to the Hotspot simultaneously.

Comment: @Izzy actually WiFi direct supports more than 1:1. But it is uncommon. After 5-6 nodes it becomes impractical as they all have to be in range of the "AP" device. But you are right that hotspot is not the same.